# Possible to check for text in driver.PageSource?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

What I mean is, would it be possible to check for keywords in the web driver's pagesource? I want to use it in an if statement like:

```
if (driver.PageSource.contains("text in url")
{
     //do something
}
```

But checking for "PageSource.contains" isn't a thing. I need it to determine what page I am on, as the driver can get redirected to a page where the elements it normally interacts with, so I need a way to get it back on track.

I'm pretty sure it's possible to check the entire URL, but I only want to check for specific text, as the URL is randomized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct function is `driver.Url`. You can check it by following:

```
bool Status= driver.Url.Contains("Enter your string");
```